# boto.connect_s3 bucket operations -> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I've been using both for a while to interface with AWS in different computers without issue until now. For some reason, in one of my machines I keep getting "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found" on boto.connect_s3 operations related to buckets.

I'm able to connect to my S3 without issues, but if I try to create a new bucket, retrieve a specific bucket or anything related to buckets, I get that error. Also, this only happens in one out of my three computers.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit** I was having the error in python 2.7.9 32 bit. I installed 2.7.9 64 bit and seems to be working fine.

This is the code I'm using, it works fine on other machines.

```
import boto

conn = boto.connect_s3()
conn.create_bucket("gbatestingbucket2")
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Sunpower\Desktop\EC2Automation\test.py", line 4, in <module>
conn.create_bucket("gbatestingbucket2")
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\connection.py", line 612, in create_bucket
data=data)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\connection.py", line 664, in make_request
retry_handler=retry_handler
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\connection.py", line 1070, in make_request
retry_handler=retry_handler)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\connection.py", line 942, in _mexe
request.body, request.headers)
File "c:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 946, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "c:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 986, in _send_request
self.putheader(hdr, value)
File "c:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 924, in putheader
str = '%s: %s' % (header, '\r\n\t'.join(values))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: I think you will need to post the relevant parts of your code and the actual stack trace you are getting.  Its pretty hard to help without those.

Comment: just added the code and traceback. Thanks!

Comment: We were seeing the same thing here as well.  Haven't tried switching python versions yet.  It seems like a bit of an odd solution.